# db_nmap metasploit using hosts in postgres database

Tags: nmap, system-administration, metasploit

I am using metasploit and attempting to run a db_nmap against all the hosts I imported from an nmap run that I saved into a .xml file. So all the hosts are in my metasploit postgres database as verified when I run the `hosts` command. However I am unsure how I can run db_nmap against all these hosts.

The typical command I use for a single IP is:
`db_nmap -sS -Pn -A --script vuln 192.0.0.1`

The command I tried to use for all IPs in my database:
`db_nmap -sS -Pn -A --script vuln hosts`

I also tried
`db_nmap -sS -Pn -A --script vuln hosts -c`

I am also currently running this as a hackaround but so far it hasn't outputted anything: `db_nmap -sS -Pn -A --script vuln -i /home/myuser/targets.txt`

I cannot find the documentation I need so I am hoping someone can help me out here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
host -o hostcsv
cat hostcsv | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | tr -d '"' | sort -u > host.txt
db_nmap --iL host.txt
```